# Electricity on magnetic powder

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields

I had the idea of, what if you ground up some magnets into a fine powder, what would happen with the powered, and how would it act? After some google searches, it seems that this isn't done very often, and that not much would come of the powder as the poles will mostly be misaligned.

So my next question was, what (if anything) would happen if you ran some electricity through some magnetic powder? Would the poles align? Could the powder be manipulated? Could it's magnetism be manipulated?

i.e If you made a magnetic powder trail in a small amplitude sine wave shape, and applied some current to it. Would the powder be able to move into a straight line, or possible break the connection (or even move at all)?

I haven't been able to find much information on this topic (of electricity WITH magnets) and I am trying to learn more on this topic.

Comment: If you do some more research, you will find that most magnetic materials are actually created from powders and that sintering and very similar operations to those that you imagine are part of the production process of magnetic materials, even though we usually  don't run an electric current trough the material directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you ground a magnet into powder, then the tiny resulting magnets would rearrange themselves into the lowest possible energy state, and that's with each N pole matching with an adjacent S pole. Yes, you could guess you'd get one long line of magnetic particles lining up into a long thin magnet, but then the next line over would line up in the exact opposite direction. Result: little or no bulk magnetic field.

If you add electricity to the situation, the electricity itself will have no effect on the magnets; it's the magnetic field generated by the electricity that will affect the magnets. Remember that electromagnets gain their strength by having many parallel windings, multiplying the effect of the current to make a strong magnet. You won't have that here, so you'd have to use a LOT of current to make a reasonable magnetic field. And, since you're acting on a powder with little or no bulk magnetic field, you'd need even more current.

My guess is that the resistive heating of the powder would become apparent long before any magnetic effects, and you'd find yourself reaching for the (hopefully nearby) fire extinguisher.